# Trouble with $mdThemingProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have defined a palette like below from the angular material example.

```
$mdThemingProvider.definePalette('amazingPaletteName', {
        '50': 'ffebee',
        '100': 'ffcdd2',
        '200': 'ef9a9a',
        '300': 'e57373',
        '400': 'ef5350',
        '500': 'f44336',
        '600': 'e53935',
        '700': 'd32f2f',
        '800': 'c62828',
        '900': 'b71c1c',
        'A100': 'ff8a80',
        'A200': 'ff5252',
        'A400': 'ff1744',
        'A700': 'd50000',
        'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',    // whether, by default, text         (contrast)
                                    // on this palette should be dark or light
        'contrastDarkColors': ['50', '100', //hues which contrast should be 'dark' by default
         '200', '300', '400', 'A100'],
        'contrastLightColors': undefined    // could also specify this if default was 'dark'
    });

   $mdThemingProvider.theme('custom2')
        .primaryPalette('amazingPaletteName');
```

Now in my html I have used it like below.

```
<div md-theme="custom2">
      <md-button class="md-primary">Button</md-button>
   </div>
```

Its showing red color, which is working as expected. But How can i choose the pallete with A700 or 500 for my button. I changed the html like below

```
<div md-theme="custom2">
          <md-button class="md-primary 500">Button</md-button>
       </div>
```

But its not having an effect. Please let me know how can i choose a different hue from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use it in my html like below.

```
<div md-theme="custom2">
          <md-button class="md-primary md-hue-1">Button</md-button>
       </div>
```